# Showing that some subset of polynomials of degree at most $3$ constitutes a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Let $P_3$ be the subspace of all real polynomials of degree at most $3$.

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a < b$. Suppose we know that $S = \{ p_0,\dots,p_3 \}$ with $p_j = (x-a)^j (x-b)^{3-j}$ is a basis of $P_3$.

Now I need to solve the following

> **Problem**: $S^{i} := (S \setminus \{ p_i \}) \cup \{ (x-c)^3 \}$ is a basis of $P_3$ for all $i = 0,\dots,3$ where $c \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a<c<b$.

**Attempt**:

Consider the linear combination
$$
(x-c)^3 = \lambda_0 p_0 + \lambda_1 p_1 + \lambda_2 p_2 + \lambda_3 p_3.
$$
From a result in our lecture, we know that if $\lambda_i \neq 0$ for some $i$, then $S^{i}$ is indeed a basis of $P_3$.

For $i=0,3$, it can be easily seen by setting $x=a$ resp. $x=b$ in the above linear combination to obtain $\lambda_0 \neq 0$ resp. $\lambda_3 \neq 0$. 
However, I have more trouble finding the argument why $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ must also be $\neq 0$.

I tried to write $(x-c)^3$ and the $p_j$'s explicitly by using the Binomial Theorem but this only ends up in a messy sum where I do not see anything.

Could you please give me a hint? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose $t$ so that $c = t a + (1-t)b$. We know that $t \neq 0$ and $1-t \neq 0$. Then

$$x-c=t(x-a)+(1-t)(x-b).$$

Plugging this into $(x-c)^3$ and applying the binomial theorem, we are done. (In the end, you will get $\lambda_i = \binom{3}{i}t^i(1-t)^{3-i}$.)